# Search any subquery bigint is exist in bigint array posgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to query a table in an array column using a subquery that is returning multiple records.
If any one of the subquery ids match in the array_column. The row should be returned in the select query.

Eg:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE bigint_array_column IN (
     SELECT id FROM table_b
)
```

bigint_array_column is '{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}'

Eg:
[image: bigint array column]

subquery data is '10, 1'.

Expected output : All the record which has 10 and 1 has to be retured.

If any one of the subquery ids exists in the bigint_array_column. I want that record to be selected in the query of table_a

I know we can do it by UNNEST the column in the select query and search it with a subquery. Is there any simpler method to do this?

**ANY** is working if the subquery returns only one record. but not for multiple records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the `&&` operator:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Comment: It works Mike, Thanks.